# uml component diagram dependency between system and component of other system

Tags: uml, modeling, enterprise-architect, component-diagram

Can I join one system with component of second subsystem by dependency ?

My intence is to show that in my system(system 2) is module / component called subsystem 1 and external system uses this subsystem.

[image: diagram]

Is this correct? Interfaces aren't defined now, so I can only show that dependency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me interpret this diagram and the answer should come naturally. :)

"System 1" depends on "Subsystem 1" in some way. "System 1" does not know anything about the "System 2", that contains the "Subsystem 1". This means that "System 1" somehow gets the direct access to "Subsystem 1", with no contact with "System 2".

Is this correct? 
That's the answer to your question. :)

Comment: So how would you paint that?

Comment: What? I've just interpreted your diagram. If it's not correct, please tell us what is not correct.

Comment: How to show that system 1 uses subsystem 1 from system 2 without defined interfaces?
edit: Or is this possible to get access to subsystem 1 without knowledge about system 2 ?

Comment: Doesn't matter. After some thoughts your interpretation is exactly what I mean. Strange system but itworks in that way.